# Can we define angular momentum for the wheel under motion?

Tags: angular-momentum, angular-velocity, gyroscopes

According to the definition of angular momentum:

> Angular momentum, moment of momentum, or rotational momentum is a vector quantity that represents the product of a body's rotational inertia and rotational velocity about a **particular axis**.[This definition has been extracted from the wiki encyclopedia-[Angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum)]

Does the wheel in motion,undergoes rotation with any particular axis of rotation (like gyroscope rotating about a particular axis), thus can we define angular momentum for it?

Comment: We can *always* define angular momentum for a rotating body regardless of the axis it rotates about. Is that what your are asking, I am not very clear on what the question is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Consider a system of $N$ particles with masses $m_i$ and positions $\mathbf x_i(t)$.  The momentum of each particle is defined is $\mathbf p _i =m \dot{\mathbf x}_i$.  The angular momentum of each particle is defined as
\begin{align}
  \mathbf L_i = \mathbf x_i\times\mathbf p_i
\end{align}
and the total angular momentum of the system is defined as the sum of the angular momenta of each of its constituent particles;
\begin{align}
  \mathbf L = \sum_{i=1}^N\mathbf L_i
\end{align}